# Rows with dates into columns - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pivot, dynamic-sql

I need some help with PIVOT tables or something to get the result in the way I need.

I've got a table like this.

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|     Client_Id |  Project_Id  | Hotel_Id | Room_Type | Room_Category |             Allotment_Date              | Number_Of_Rooms | Number_Booked | Number_Available | Overbook | Price | Dep_Amount | Full_Payment | Admin_Only | HotelAllotment_Id | Price_Excl_VAT | VAT_Code | Charge_Dep_Amount |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2423 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-05 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 33000 |          0 |            1 |          0 |            279611 |              0 |          |                 0 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2423 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-06 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 33000 |          0 |            1 |          0 |            279612 |              0 |          |                 0 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2423 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-07 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 33000 |          0 |            1 |          0 |            279613 |              0 |          |                 0 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2424 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-05 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 22000 |      22000 |            0 |          0 |            279590 |              0 |          |                 0 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2424 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-06 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 22000 |      22000 |            0 |          0 |            279591 |              0 |          |                 0 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2424 |       276 |               |                     2010-12-07 00:00:00 |           99999 |             1 |            99998 |        0 | 22000 |      22000 |            0 |          0 |            279592 |              0 |          |                 0 |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
```

I need the data to be displayed like this, to get the dates in columns and the number booked per day.

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|     Client_Id |  Project_Id  | Hotel_Id | Room_Type | Room_Category | 2010-12-05 | 2010-12-06 | 2010-12-07   |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2423 |       276 |               |          1 |          1 |            1 |
|     DEFAULT   |     TEMPLATE |     2424 |       276 |               |          1 |          1 |            1 |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

I need this to be grouped by Hotel_Id, Room_Type and Room_Category (if any)

I need this to be dynamic because the dates can change.

I tried using simple pivot tables with no luck.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result before writing a dynamic version I would suggest writing a static version first.

If you have a limited number of values, then you can hard-code all of the `dates` to be the columns headers:

```
select client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
  room_type, room_category,
  [2010-12-05], [2010-12-06], [2010-12-07]
from 
(
  select client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
    room_type, room_category,
    allotment_date, number_booked
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  sum(number_booked)
  for allotment_date in ([2010-12-05], [2010-12-06], [2010-12-07])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c89c/5).  But if your values will be unknown then you will need to create a sql string to be executed using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), allotment_date, 120)) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by allotment_date
                    order by allotment_date
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
                room_type, room_category,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
                room_type, room_category,
                allotment_date, number_booked
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(number_booked)
                for allotment_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c89c/6). These give the result:

```
| CLIENT_ID | PROJECT_ID | HOTEL_ID | ROOM_TYPE | ROOM_CATEGORY | 2010-12-05 | 2010-12-06 | 2010-12-07 |
|-----------|------------|----------|-----------|---------------|------------|------------|------------|
|   DEFAULT |   TEMPLATE |     2423 |       276 |        (null) |          1 |          1 |          1 |
|   DEFAULT |   TEMPLATE |     2424 |       276 |        (null) |          1 |          1 |          1 |
```

Comment: It's good but with big project that have lots of hotels and the date range is not the same per hotel it give an error.
"Msg 1056, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements. "
The project I'm testing has 4641 records

Comment: @FedericoGiust There are limits in place as to what can be returned, if you really need to pivot 4641 different values of data, then you should consider breaking this up into smaller pieces or do this type of transformation in your application layer not in SQL.

Comment: @FedericoGiust Then that's a sign that what you are doing isn't something that should be done in the database layer

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Further discussion about this "solution" has indicated that it would be prudent to go into further detail as to *why* this shouldn't ever be used as reliable code.  Outside of the obvious NEVER EVERs like `SELECT  *`, going down this path only beats the compile time limitation.  Assuming we populated the `@t_Date` table variable with the following ( and way, way better ) CTE:

```
    -- Thanks @AaronBertrand!
    WITH cte_Date(DateVal) AS (
        SELECT TOP (10000) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
                   OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id), '19991231')
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    )
    INSERT INTO @t_Date ( DateVal )
    SELECT  DateVal
    FROM    cte_Date;
```

Inevitably, we'll run across a message like the following at some point:

> Msg 8632, Level 17, State 2, Line 2
>
> Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

Note that even the error message can be summarized with, as @bluefeet and @Lamak have more or less stated, "Don't do that in the data layer."

So, as the post was:

@bluefeet and @Lamak are two of the highest caliber database people on StackOverflow, so you will want to heed their words.  If you *really* need to test this, using @bluefeet's answer, since you are receiving a compile-time error, you can cheese the hell out of your query and get around this through the following example.  Please, for sake of anybody who may need to take over the responsibilities of your job, **do not move code like this into a production environment**.  I post this hack-fest workaround only so that you can test whatever theory you're working on and the follow up through the appropriate steps to make your data layer more suitable for deployment.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'yourtable'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.yourtable;
    CREATE TABLE dbo.yourtable
    (    
        [Client_Id] varchar(7), 
        [Project_Id] varchar(8), 
        [Hotel_Id] int, 
        [Room_Type] int, 
        [Room_Category] int, 
        [Allotment_Date] datetime, 
        [Number_Of_Rooms] int, 
        [Number_Booked] int, 
        [Number_Available] int, 
        [Overbook] int, 
        [Price] int, 
        [Dep_Amount] int, 
        [Full_Payment] int, 
        [Admin_Only] int, 
        [HotelAllotment_Id] int, 
        [Price_Excl_VAT] int, 
        [VAT_Code] int, 
        [Charge_Dep_Amount] INT
    );

    DECLARE @t_Date    TABLE
    (
        DateVal        DATE
    );

    WITH cte_Date AS (
        SELECT  DateVal = CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DateVal = DATEADD( DAY, -1, DateVal )
        FROM    cte_Date
        WHERE   DateVal > '2002-01-01'  
    )
    INSERT INTO @t_Date ( DateVal )
    SELECT  DateVal
    FROM    cte_Date
    OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 5000 );

    INSERT INTO dbo.yourtable( [Client_Id], [Project_Id], [Hotel_Id], [Room_Type], [Room_Category], [Allotment_Date], 
        [Number_Of_Rooms], [Number_Booked], [Number_Available], [Overbook], [Price], [Dep_Amount], [Full_Payment], 
        [Admin_Only], [HotelAllotment_Id], [Price_Excl_VAT], [VAT_Code], [Charge_Dep_Amount] )
    SELECT  'DEFAULT', 'TEMPLATE', 2423, 276, NULL, DateVal, 99999, 1, 99998, 0, 33000, 0, 1, 0, 279611, 0, NULL, 0
    FROM    @t_Date;
END;
GO

SELECT  COUNT( DISTINCT Allotment_date )
FROM    dbo.yourtable;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), allotment_date, 120)) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by allotment_date
                    order by allotment_date
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
            SELECT  *
            FROM (    SELECT client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
                        room_type, room_category,' + @cols + ' 
                    from 
                    (
                      select client_id, project_id, hotel_id,
                        room_type, room_category,
                        allotment_date, number_booked
                      from yourtable
                    ) x
                    pivot 
                    (
                        sum(number_booked)
                        for allotment_date in (' + @cols + ')
                    ) p ) a;'

execute sp_executesql @query;
GO
```